# Want to Install Ubuntu over Linux Mint

Tags: ubiquity

I have a dual boot computer with both Linux Mint and Windows 7 on it. I want to run ubuntu instead of linux mint. How do I get rid of Linux Mint and still keep Windows 7 without damage to grub also.

Answer (score 1):

During installation of Ubuntu there are few options:

[image]

You can choose "Something else":

[image]

and here choose disks of your Mint to format and set as `/` and `/home` or whatever partition you want for Ubuntu. Grub will be edited automatically, and Windows should stay in.